# www.sitename.com not rediecting to https://www.sitename.com

Tags: windows, iis, mod-rewrite, server

I need something as below for IIS mod_rewrite

1. `http://www.example.com` redirect to `https://www.example.com`
2. `example.com` to `https://www.example.com`
3. `www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

This one that I am using and `www.sitename.com` to `sitename.com` is NOT WORKING - Getting 404 error:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="sitename.com{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Please add everything that you've tried to the question itself, not to the comment section. Additionally explain what exactly does not work yet

Answer (score 0):

This should move http to https, just add the code below to your `web.config`

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
          <match url="(.*)" /> 
          <conditions> 
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions> 
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule> 
      </rules> 
    </rewrite> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For apache users just add this code below to the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I am hosted site in IIS Windows 2012. .htacess will be work on it?

Comment: I need for Windows .webconfig file

Comment: Thank you. I tried with your webconfig and its not working. When i enter www.servername.com then its not redirecting, its going to 404 page @David

Comment: @Matrix try this new one, if it doesnt work you should consider to add your `web.config` code in the post description

Comment: I tried with your new one. The thing is when we enter without any http or https then its redirecting. But in browser when entering www.sitename.com its not working. or http://www.sitename.com too not working. I am using LetEncrypt SSL

Comment: <rewrite> <rules> <clear /> <rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="(.*)" /> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny"> <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" /> <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" /> </conditions> <action type="Redirect" url="sitename.com{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" /> </rule> </rules> </rewrite> Its the one what I am using now

Comment: Thank you.. Finally it got worked. I added a Bindings for www.sitename.com and its get worked now. Thanks for you valuable help